# Exception Value: no such column: blog_app_article.slug in django

Tags: django

I have a problem with slug.
my code is running well but just when I add

```
slug=models.SlugField(default=True,max_length=40)
```

to my model. it stops and give me the error :

```
OperationalError at / no such column: blog_app_article.slug
```

when I delete the slug, my code run well again.

[image]

I've deleted database and make it again but it doesnt work.

what's the problem?

I'm coding on Pycharm 2020.1.3 and Django 4.0.4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

done!
make another app and it fixed!!!!

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).